# Building a .DPK for 64bit C++Builder?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I have a 3rd party provided `.dpk` that I build using `dcc32` and it works fine, but for `dcc64` I get an error:

> packagename.dpk(35) Fatal: E2202 Required package 'designide' not found

Which, from what I've read online, is because the IDE itself is only 32-bit and there is no 64-bit alternative, and that has something to do with integrating with the IDE.

How do I build the 64-bit libraries for me to use with C++Builder 64bit Windows target?

Comment: Contact the third party vendor and have them fix their product, to properly separate design-time and run-time code. You should be able to build a run-time package that has no dependencies on the designer, and a separate design time package that uses that runtime library at design time. There is never a need for a 64-bit design time package, because (as you mentioned), the IDE is 32 bit.

Comment: The IDE is indeed a 32bit program. The `designide` package is used by other packages to interact with the IDE itself, so there is only a 32bit version, no 64bit version. **Run-time** packages SHOULD NOT reference `designide` at all, only **design-time** packages should. It sounds like your `dpk`'s code is not properly separated into run-time and design-time packages. OLD versions of Delphi/C++Builder let you get away with that, but modern versions do not. If the `.dpk` does not contain any design-time editors or IDE add-ons, then there is no reason for it to reference `designide` at all

Comment: @RemyLebeau It offers a component in the IDE you can drop on a form.  If I wanted to separate it, are there key functions I can look for to tell which is for design time and which are for run time?

Comment: You can find a nice article about [Creating Packages](https://delphi.fandom.com/wiki/Creating_Packages) on Delphi Fandom. It covers creating both runt-ime and design-time packages

Comment: @user3161924 All code for the component itself (including `RegisterComponents()`) needs to be in a run-time package. All code for the IDE (ie, property editors, component editors, etc) needs to be in a design-time package that `requires` the run-time package. Only the design-time package is installed in the IDE. Read Embarcadero's documentation on [Working with Packages and Components](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Working_with_Packages_and_Components_Index) and [VCL Component Writer's Guide](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/VCL_Component_Writer%27s_Guide_Index).